# Title Page for PhD Interview Presentation

Tags: phd, application, presentation

**Background information:** I am currently applying for various PhD programs in Mathematics. For some of them, I have to give a short presentation regarding the research proposal, which I have submitted for the application.

Now, I am currently a research assistant in the university where I did my master's degree in order to continue my work until I can start my PhD. However, my PhD applications are for other universities in slightly different topics.

**My question(s):**

1. I usually include my affiliation as well as the name and the logo of
   my university on the title page, because it looks more prefessional.
   Should I also do this for the PhD interview? On one hand, the
   application has nothing to do with my university and currenct
   academic position (I mean, I do not present anything regarding my
   research, just the project on which I intend to work as a PhD
   student), but on the other hand it is the place where I am currently
   affilated to.
2. Secondly, should I include the name of my intended supervisor on the title page? For the application, it was not required to specify
   your preferred supervisor, however, I am already in touch with some
   professors and the proposals are the results of my discussions with them (the proposal are not binding, just required for the applications).
   So, should I add a line on the title page like "*intended to work
   under the guidance of Prof. John/Jane Doe*"? (The professors are in each case not in the committee)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) is OK, since you are currently working there.
(2) seems to me to be a bit presumptuous since the person you are naming has not yet accepted you. The committee will ask you about who you want to work with anyway and hopefully, your advisor *in spe* has already indicated this to the committee.